# Input from Kattis submission checker

Tags: php

Learning PHP I choose to work on [Neighborhood Watch](https://open.kattis.com/problems/neighborhoodwatch). I believe that I have a working solution locally. I'm looking to get help simply importing the answers from the site. I did look at the help section which gave me this:

```
while (fscanf(STDIN, '%d%d', $number1, $number2) === 2) {}
```

But it gives no information on getting as many inputs as needed. In the example above, number1 and number2 will always be entered. I'm looking to take number2 and get more inputs equal to number2. Ive found similar questions in java and c++, but not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well after I finished my project and remembered that I saw this on here, I thought I would chime in and give a response.

Since each house number is a separate input, you can do a for loop using the 2nd input variable as your max number.

Example:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number2; $i++) {
    while (fscanf(STDIN, '%d', $houseNumber) === 1) {}
    // Do something with $houseNumber
    // An array to hold the values or something to calculate the safety rating
}
```

Just my thought process. Best wishes this semester.

Answer (score 0):

The input format (via STDIN) for this problem is `n`, `k` and a series of house numbers of neighborhood watch houses `h`, all integers:

```
n k
h
h
```

For example:

```
5 2
1
4
```

You can collect `k` and loop that many times to collect the input, or simply read until `fscanf` returns something other than 1 (the return value indicates how many variables were scanned).

For example:

```php
<?php

fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d", $n, $k);
$neighborhood_watch_houses = [];

while (fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $h) === 1) {
    $neighborhood_watch_houses[] = $h;
}

var_dump($n);
var_dump($k);
var_dump($neighborhood_watch_houses);
```

Sample run:

```
5 2
1
4

int(5)
int(2)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Alternatively:

```php
<?php

fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d", $n, $k);
$neighborhood_watch_houses = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $k; $i++) {
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $h);
    $neighborhood_watch_houses[] = $h;
}

var_dump($n);
var_dump($k);
var_dump($neighborhood_watch_houses);
```